# Generate interface from solid class file in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, interface, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

Is there any plugin in `Eclipse` that auto generates `interface` based on solid class/impl concrete `class`?
Currently I hand code interfaces.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Just choose **Extract Interface...** from the `Refactor` menu.

[image]

Comment: Works better if you set all methods you want to be generated in the interfaces as non-static... (I had this problem)

Comment: This breaks if I'm using eclipse. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Worked for me in Eclipse - I had forgotten how to do it/where to find it